# Is this Dualshock 2 controller bootleg?

Tags: controllers, ps2

A few days ago I bought a Dualshock 2 controller and some PS2 games at a thrift store. The controller was really cheap, $1.99, but the cases were separating from each other. It looked like an easy enough fix, so I bought it. It worked and functioned well like I'd expect Sony stuff to. The only issue being that due to the case separating along the top, R2 stuck a little when pressed.

I took it and another Dualshock 2 (a broken one to use for parts) apart today and found something odd: the Dualshock 2 logic boards looked completely different, with the board inside the thrift store one not looking like any other out there on the Internet.

Thrift Store

[image: Thrift Store PCB]

Regular

[image: Regular PCB]

Especially the connector...

Thrift Store

[image: Thrift Store Connector]

Regular

[image: Regular Connector]

Also the part of the frame where the shoulder buttons rest is way different and a lot more fragile. They were broken in the thrift store one and I tried to fix it with a glue gun.

Thrift Store

[image: Thrift Store Shoulder Button]

Regular

[image: Regular Shoulder Button]

Additionally, the buttons on each were different and would only fit in whichever controller they were a part of.

[image: Face Buttons, Both]

I'm a Nintendo fan and when dealing with SNES controllers (especially the ones that shipped with the redesigned console) a good place to start looking is the text on the back. Maybe it's the same here.

Thrift Store

[image: Thrift Store Shell Back]

Regular

[image: Regular Shell Back]

I hate 3rd-party accessories, whether it's for my game consoles, iPhone 6s, MacBook Pro, or anything else I own. Bootleg products ripping of the original is the only thing, IMO, that's worse.

I'm kind of thinking that this is a bootleg controller, but I'm not sure. If it was, the bootlegger went to great lengths to make it look and feel like an official one. Is it bootleg?

Comment: Its been a long time since I have seen the insides of an old PS2 controller. But the thirft store board looks a lot more familiar then your alt example

Comment: The only difference I see on the back part of the controller is that the thrift store one is marked with A and the other is marked with H. This could mean that the thrift store one is an older model then the other one.

Comment: @Lyrion They both have the same model number, though... `SCPH-10010`.

Comment: @Lyrion Although you're apparently right.  The A model is the original while the H model was made at the same time as the PS2 Slim, likely as a cost saving measure.

Comment: That would make a lot more sense, especially since the same store was also selling a PS2 Slim separately.

Comment: @Powerlord Same _part_ number, SCPH-10010, different _model_ or _revision_ "number" (A vs. H).

Answer (score -3):

I think your controller is legitimate. I am presuming this only as i do notice one difference in the bottom of the controller to the right of the scei you have different letters one is an A the other is H....this is most likely hardware revision enumeration. Either way im supprised you are using analog sticks instead of digital dual shock with ps2 if you are so opposed to lower quality builds....